# FFMPEG - Short video - Loop to make it bigger

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg

I create animated video.
But the video is very short.

So i am trying to increase the length of the video. It is animated, so it will not make any difference.

I am doing it with cat function.
Is there anyway to loop it without using the concat?

I create mp4. To copy the videos i convert them to mpg. Again i convert them to mp4. It is a long process. So, If i can increase the timing by looping the video, I don't need to do other convert process. Is it possible in ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I found its best to use the same approach.  I tried looping using the concat filter in ffmpeg, but it would run out of memory quit easily.